# Getting low to medium FPS on a fairly decent mid-range notebook. What could the bottleneck be?

Tags: gaming, fps

I have a Lenovo Z470 laptop and these are its specs (generated from Speccy):

**Operating System:** Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1

**CPU:** Intel Core i5 2450M @ 2.50GHz, Sandy Bridge 32nm Technology

**RAM:** 8.00 GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 665MHz (9-9-9-24)

**Motherboard:** LENOVO KL6 (CPU)

**Graphics:** ThinkPad Display 1366x768 (1366x768@60Hz), NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M, Intel HD Graphics 3000

**Hard Drives:** 466GB Seagate ST9500325AS (SATA), 5400 RPM. C:\ = 60.1GB free of 113GB, D:\ = 45.6GB free of 228GB

**Optical Drives:** OPY C9EJ0DUV SCSI CdRom Device, MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8B1AS

**Audio:** Realtek High Definition Audio

Anything else I need to add? I'm usually getting 30 to 40+ FPS when I'm playing Borderlands (the first game) and Just Cause 2. I use 1366x768 resolution but pretty much every other game video settings are set to mid or low.

My video card drivers are up-to-date, I don't run any other applications when I'm playing (except for Fraps). And being that my laptop has Optimus Technology, I make sure my games are utilizing my Nvidia card. If this matters, my games are installed in drive D:.

Do I perhaps need to adjust settings in my Nvidia control panel? Or free up some disk space? What do you think is the bottleneck of my laptop's gaming performance? Thank you.

Comment: 30 to 40 FPS is probably the maximum your display is capable of. Movies in theaters are 24 FPS, so I can't imagine why you would describe that as "low to medium".

Comment: Check out the core config on your [GPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units#GeForce_600M_.286xxM.29_series), it's quite crippled.

Comment: should be on Arqade (gaming.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about posting there, sorry. @DavidSchwartz, I was just comparing the FPS I'm getting to the FPS other people mostly are getting, which is 60+.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин, how is that true? When you partner a high-end video card to a low-end processor, wouldn't the processor be the bottleneck?

Comment: @d4ryl3 My written statements are not law. You may interpret them as you please. What I meant was: In my experience, it is very common, if not always the case that the GPU is the reason for low FPS in games. The thing is, graphically-heavy games require a lot more GPU power than they require CPU power. I don't have a technical and detailed explanation of this, thus the short subjective comment above. The reason I voted your question down, is because even if this is not obvious to you - as it is to me, researching this subject on the net would have given you the same idea in less than 20 min.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин First: I'll acknowledge that my GPU is holding the performance back, no problem. Second: Exactly my point, you can't say that the GPU is always the bottleneck. Your first comment was based on your own experience. Third: I could have researched the net on this but I didn't, due to the fact that my notebook's specs are most probably unique from others. So I came here for a notebook-specific analysis. That doesn't sound like a valid reason for a vote down. Anyway, I'll let it go. I got my answers. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notebook's specs is a fairly decent midrange workstation, it is not a midrange gaming laptop. The GPU is really low powered for any gaming purpose. For a midrange gaming laptop, I'd be expecting at least 660M or for older laptops 570M. There isn't much you could do if your GPU isn't up to the task.

Comment: Hmmm, I was kind of expecting that. Anyway, would you have any idea of some Nvidia settings that perhaps I could adjust to increase (or at least maintain good) FPS? Thank you.

Comment: @d4ryl3 This is not a support service for your particular laptop-graphics card configuration. Questions should be specific, but not that specific. Again, Do Your Research. Increasing FPS is a very popular subject.